# Which directory does python-setuptools' easy_install put console_scripts to?

Tags: python, easy-install, egg

`easy_install` generates launcher scripts based on the value of `console_scripts` in egg info. It appears that an egg does not specify the full path, how can I check if the generated script will be put to `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, or elsewhere?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly. Do you need to check for easy_install and setuptools directories?

```
#finds the path to easy_install if it exists
which easy_install

#where path/to/easy_install is the output from the above command
#this outputs your easy_install script which will mention the version of setuptools
less path/to/easy_install
```

Comment: No, e.g. there is supervisor egg, that has "supervisorctl = ..." in console_scripts, sometimes it's put to to /usr/bin/, sometimes to /usr/local/bin, I want to know why

Comment: Could you print your PATH variable?